# How to get a graph axis into standard form

Tags: python, graph, numpy, matplotlib

I have plotted a graph where the scale on the y axis is large (10^6) however at the moment the axis is displaying the whole number. How can i get the axis to be displayed in standard form?

```
range_v=142
max_actual_diff=0
max_ID=0.0

for i in range(0,fev[ind_2008].shape[0]):

    id_temp=ID[ind_2008[i]]

    ind_2009_temp=np.where(ID[ind_2009] == id_temp)
    actual_diff=fev[ind_2008[i]]-fev[ind_2009[ind_2009_temp]]

    if actual_diff > max_actual_diff:
        max_actual_diff=actual_diff
        max_ID=id_temp
    diff=np.abs(fev[ind_2008][i]-fev_p1)
    pdf_t, bins_t=np.histogram(diff,bins=range_v-1,range=(0,range_v))
    if i == 0:
        pdf=pdf_t
        pdf[:]=0.0
    pdf=pdf+pdf_t

print max_actual_diff, max_ID
#plot result
x=[max_actual_diff]*3000001
y=np.arange(0,3.000001e6,1)
bincenters = 0.5*(bins_t[1:]+bins_t[:-1])
fig3=plt.figure()
plt.plot(bincenters,pdf)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlim(0,142)
plt.ylim(0,3e6)
plt.xlabel('Diff in FEV Measurements')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.legend(['Diff in FEV Measurements','max diff between recorded fevpctECFSPR'],loc='best')
plt.title('FEVPCT')
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('FEV.jpg')
```

Comment: Dont understand why there isnt just an option to make the axis standard form. If i increase the ylim to 3e7 it automatically changes it to standard form

Comment: @blablabla apparently you can just do: `plt.gca().ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0,1), axis='y')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by manually setting the format strings for the yticks:

```
x = plt.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = 1e6 + plt.sin(x)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_yticklabels(["{:.6e}".format(t) for t in ax.get_yticks()])
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The important part is `{:6e}".format(t)` this states we want exponential form (standard form) with 6 S.F. There is also a call to subplots adjust so that the entire length of the number is shown.

EDIT: Having seen your comment I believe you could achieve a similar effect by setting the default params:

```
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = [-5,5]
```

The default is `[-7, 7]`!

Comment: you edit answer is perfect, i thought there must be a way to change its default setting and that does it, thanks