# Relocate the "ten raised to the power" in scientific notation of z axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a 3D figure whose z axis is written in scientific notation. However, the "ten raised to the power" of the sci notation is located at the left and not at top of the axis, and therefore, it is overlapping with the zlabel text. Is there one line command or any other solution to relocate this number and put it at the top.

PD:
For a given data matrix Sigma_ww, the code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

sigma_ww = np.loadtxt("Sigma_ww_post.txt",delimiter=',')
xx       = np.linspace(0,5,100)
X, Y     = np.meshgrid(xx, xx)

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 25, 'text.usetex': True})
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax  = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, sigma_ww, rstride=5, cstride=5, cmap=cm.pink)
ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$x\prime$')
ax.zaxis.set_rotate_label(False) 
ax.set_zlabel('$C_{ww|\\tilde{w}}(x,x^\prime)$',rotation=90)
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 5)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, Sigma_ww.max())
ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=-130)
ax.xaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor'] = 2.0
ax.yaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor'] = 2.0
ax.zaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor'] = 2.0
ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='z', scilimits=(0,0), useOffset=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and the figure looks like this:
[image: COV]

Comment: So the z axis limits are between `-0.2  -  1.0 (*10 ^ -6)` and it has automatically placed the (*10 ^ -6) on the edge of the z axis? Are the x and y values also (*10 ^ -6) ?

Comment: Can you mess around with `plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = [-7,7]` and see if it changes the location of *10. The [-7,7] is the default format. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529657/how-to-get-a-graph-axis-into-standard-form.  Also, can you post a sample your 3 arrays: that way others can run it and play around themselves.

Comment: the item you need to modify is called the `offset_text`. You can access it from `ax.zaxis.get_offset_text()`, although I'm not sure how easy it is to modify from there.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your suggestions. I tried the `plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = [-7,7]` and the `ax.zaxis.offset_text_position= "top"` options but none of them worked. I found a  solution which is basically to scale the data as `Sigma_ww = Sigma_ww*1e7` and then put the `x10^{-7}` "manually" using `ax.text2D(0.06, 0.81, '$\\times 10^{-7}$', transform=ax.transAxes)`, it looks very nice. However, I will leave the question opened in case someone proposes a solution by controlling the `zaxis` properties.